# Here-Maps Android SDK not having WaypointParameterType to add as waypoint

Tags: navigation, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am using Here Android SDK for Navigation, I am planning a route which has around 100 waypoints b/w source and destination. 
So i am adding waypoints for the RoutePlan as

routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(XXXXXXXXXXX,  YYYYYYYYYYYY), RouteWaypoint.Type.VIA_WAYPOINT)

But as per documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html
We can set TransitRadius and Heading parameters also for waypoints, Can i know the these parameters context and how to use in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep care not to mix the Routing REST API (you linked in the original post) with the MobileSDK documentation. Even many features are the same, there are differences.

If you use the MobileSDK for Navigation, you probably refer to the Premium Mobile SDK, and the documentation is here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/

For waypoints, you can set the WaypointDirection in the RouteWaypoint class: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteWaypoint.html

TransitRadius is not implemented in the Premium MobileSDK at the moment.

Btw: In case you use the Starter Mobile SDK (that has no Navigation support), also the WaypointDirection is not supported there.

Answer (score 0):

To add a waypoint, you can simply use:

```
Waypoint waypoint1 = new Waypoint(new GeoCoordinates(your geocordinates));
Waypoint waypoint2 = new Waypoint(new GeoCoordinates(your geocordinates));
```

Also, now in explore edition as well, you can route type as well. Route Type means whether your route is Stopover type or Pass-Through type, below I am showing how to set waypoint as pass-through type. By Default, all the waypoints added will be STOP Over type.

```
waypoint1.type = WaypointType.PASS_THROUGH;
waypoint2.type = WaypointType.PASS_THROUGH;
```